# Avoiding divide by zero error when using the OVER() clause even after using nullif

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

The error I'm getting is

> Divide by zero error encountered.

My code looks like:

```
Select A, B, C, nullif(100*count / sum(count) OVER (partition by A, B), 0) as Share
```

Any ideas why this may be throwing me an error?

Answer (score 1):

You want `nullif()` around the denominator of the division, not around the whole operation:

```
select a, b, c, 
    100 * count / nullif(sum(count) over (partition by a, b), 0) as share
from ...
```

That way, if the window sum returns `0`, `nullif()` turns it to a `null` value, which avoids the division by zero error - and you get a `null` value as a result to the division.

Side note: `count` is a language keyword, hence not a good choice for a column name.

Answer (score 1):

Because if the `sum(count)` is returning `0`. The `NULLIF` should be around that expression, not the whole thing:

```sql
Select A, B, C, 100*count / nullif(sum(count) OVER (partition by A, B), 0) as Share
```